# Syntax for including fields dynamically in CSOM query?

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query

What is the proper syntax for including fields dynamically in a CSOM listitems query?

For example, this would apparently work:

```
foreach (string field in fields)
{
  clientContext.Load(items, includes => includes.Include(i => i[field]));
}
```

but what would be the correct / best syntax?

As a comparison - if we know the fields beforehand we could write:

```
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
clientContext.Load(items, includes => includes.Include(
   i => i["Field1"], 
   i => i["Field2"]));
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For demonstration purposes, let's assume we have a custom list named Phones with the following fields:

- Title (manufacturer)
- Model

According to [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), the query:

```
var fieldNames = new[] { "Title", "Model" };
 foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
 {
                    context.Load(items, includes => includes.Include(i => i[fieldName]));
 }
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

and query

```
context.Load(items, includes => includes.Include(i => i["Title"], i => i["Model"]));
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

generate absolutely identical Request that is sent to SharePoint WCF Web Service `/_vti_bin/client.svc/`

```
<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="15.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009">
  <Actions>
    <Query Id="15" ObjectPathId="10">
      <Query SelectAllProperties="false">
        <Properties />
      </Query>
      <ChildItemQuery SelectAllProperties="false">
        <Properties>
          <Property Name="Title" ScalarProperty="true" />
          <Property Name="Model" ScalarProperty="true" />
        </Properties>
      </ChildItemQuery>
    </Query>
  </Actions>
  <ObjectPaths>
    <Method Id="10" ParentId="7" Name="GetItems">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter TypeId="{3d248d7b-fc86-40a3-aa97-02a75d69fb8a}">
          <Property Name="DatesInUtc" Type="Boolean">true</Property>
          <Property Name="FolderServerRelativeUrl" Type="Null" />
          <Property Name="ListItemCollectionPosition" Type="Null" />
          <Property Name="ViewXml" Type="String">
            &lt;View Scope="RecursiveAll"&gt;&#xD;
            &lt;Query&gt;&#xD;
            &lt;/Query&gt;&#xD;
            &lt;/View&gt;
          </Property>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
    </Method>
    <Identity Id="7" Name="740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:f0a52fd4-bd00-4bdb-a831-38df487f7f02:web:234535de-cbdf-4b3a-9f70-5fb97c73f92f:list:60633b9c-4acf-442e-b18b-ef413046b8e3" />
  </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

Summary: from the perspective of performance, for the specified cases, it does not matter how to specify fields that should be retrieved