# CSOM: fetching items using ViewFields and non-default properties

Tags: csom, caml

I'm trying to get a particular set of columns for items in a list, as well as RoleAssignments which is a non-default property.

Assuming my CAML, where I define my ViewFields, is in a variable `CAMLtemplate`, I can get the desired columns:

```
clientContext.Load(CAMLtemplate);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

However when I add the additional properties, it seems I'm no longer getting the **columns** I've specified in my CAML:

```
clientContext.Load(CAMLtemplate, 
    iCol => iCol.Include(
                 item => item.RoleAssignments,
                 item => item.RoleAssignments.Include(
                                              ra => ra.Member.LoginName,
                                              ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings)));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

...I get an error when trying to work with a column I've requested in my CAML, like `The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`

This seems to suggest that I either need to explicitly request every column in my `iCol.Include` (seems crazy, there are lots of columns, and why bother with the CAML ViewFields if this is the case?), or do something else. How can I simply get the columns I want, as well as the additional property I want?

Comment: Try to use **clientContext.ExecuteQuery();** just after **clientContext.Load(CAMLtemplate);** & then after try to apply query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that by putting my two calls to the `Load` method one after the other, I could retrieve the columns and then the further attributes. I still don't understand why this can't be done in a single call, but [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89634/syntax-for-including-fields-dynamically-in-csom-query) gave me the clue I needed. This works:

```
clientContext.Load(CAMLtemplate);
clientContext.Load(CAMLtemplate, 
     iCol => iCol.Include(
                 item => item.RoleAssignments,
                 item => item.RoleAssignments.Include(
                                          ra => ra.Member.LoginName,
                                          ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings)));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are using the property of the object which is not yet initialized. So to initialize this just write

```
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

after the line:

```
clientContext.Load(CAMLtemplate);
```

**Please see below example**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class RetrieveListItems
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1} \nBody: {2}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"], oListItem["Body"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more clarification to load fields, Please see below links.

[Syntax for including fields dynamically in CSOM query?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89634/syntax-for-including-fields-dynamically-in-csom-query)

[How to include custom fields in clientContext.load()?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128650/how-to-include-custom-fields-in-clientcontext-load)

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have `ExecuteQuery` before I try to access the properties. The point of my question is about mixing CAML ViewFields with the Include for additional properties in the `Load` method.

Comment: For your concern, Please check the answer here..https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128650/how-to-include-custom-fields-in-clientcontext-load as well as https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89634/syntax-for-including-fields-dynamically-in-csom-query

Comment: Did you got the solution? If yes then i will put above comment in my answer. :)

Comment: Aha. So I can actually just make the 2 `Load` calls one after each other, to cumulatively specify in `Load`s what I want. Maybe there's some doco I've missed, it wasn't very clear, but your second link gave me the clue. Thanks!

Comment: You can accept my answer or urs so user will find solution from it. Added both links in my answer. It might help others. :)