# Load specific elements in a collection

Tags: csom

There are hundreds of fields in the library but I am interested in just a few. The following code does not work:

```
string[] fieldNames = {"field1", "field2", ..., "fieldN"};
var fields = context.LoadQuery(context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(" My List").Fields
   .Where(x => fieldNames.Contains(x.Title))
   .Include(fld =>fld.Title, fld=>fld.InternalName));
```

The run-time message is "The 'Contains' member cannot be used in the expression.".

I could write `.Where(x => (x.Title == "field1" || x.Title == "field2" ...))`
or construct a CAML query dynamically, but is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and as far as I can find on the Internet, the `Any` and `Contains` keywords are not supported in this scenario.

So you are stuck with using a fixed number of conditions with the `||` operator or a dynamically constructed CAML query, unless someone else may be able to provide a different solution.

Comment: This code produces the same result: "The 'Any' member cannot be used in the expression".

Comment: Even if it ran, would it do what I want it to do: From MSDN:

"This method does not return any one element of a collection. Instead, it
determines whether any elements of a collection satisfy a condition."

The set of all fields in the list *must* include the small subset that I want.

Comment: You are right. I should have tested the `Any` and `Contains` keywords before posting an answer. I am going to update my answer with a working example.

Comment: Loading in a loop (see answer below) seems as if it will work. If I wanted to try a CAML query, which list would I query? I need the structure of the list, not the contents. Does SharePoint expose lists like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views in MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article which uses foreach loop to automate the include fields. This might solve your problem.

```
var fieldNames = new[] { "Title", "Model" };
foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
{
    context.Load(items, includes => includes.Include(i => i[fieldName]));
}
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

[Syntax for including fields dynamically in CSOM query?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89634/syntax-for-including-fields-dynamically-in-csom-query)

Comment: This looks good. I will be able to test it in a few hours.

Comment: The line
`context.Load(myList.Fields, includes => includes.Include(i => i[fieldName]));`
is syntactically incorrect. The message is "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expresion of type'Field'". When I change it to
 
`context.Load(myList.Fields, includes => includes.Include(i => i.Title == fieldName));`
the message is 'The query expression is not supported'.

Comment: The line `context.Load(items, x => x.Where(i => i.Title == fieldName));` is OK on the first iteration but on the next it throws an exception "The query expression is not supported".